# Create Laravel project with composer not working

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I installed with success composer.phar in my computer but when I try to create a Laravel project with composer I have this error "exportnot open input file: path". Here you can see a print of terminal:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel IsabellProgetto
```

Answer (score 1):

`composer create-project laravel/laravel newproject`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-project-name "5.2.*"
```